# how to use c# struct from f#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

what's the syntax for using a c# struct in f#? how do i assign it's fields values?

thanks!

update:

looks like i can declare the variable itself mutable and then set it's fields using the <- operator...is there another way?

Comment: If you use ints, bools, datetimes, and enums in your F#, then you're already using structs -- I'm not really sure which part is giving your problem. Can you post a piece of C#, maybe someone can convert it to F# for you?

Comment: @Juliet: Brian's answer supplies an example, this is what i was after. basically i have a struct defined in c# and i need to populate it from f#. my first feeling was that i would be able to use record syntax for it since it's a value type, but it turned out that i had to make it look like a mutable class and set it's fields like one would set properties. this is a bit unfortunate but understandable, i just did not figure it out right away :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> looks like i can declare the variable
>   itself mutable and then set it's
>   fields using the <- operator...is
>   there another way?

This is the correct thing to do.

```
let mutable someStruct = CallSomething()
someStruct.Field1 <- 42
// etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you require something like that?

```
open System.Drawing
let point = Point(X = 1, Y = 3)
```